# Transition effect on toggle jquery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I am trying to to make a hidden menu with jquery toggle.
I have a button with a click event and a class menu with a toggle event.
I want to make a CSS transition on the menu, or an effect to appear.

I have a sidebar and I want to the menu to appear from left to right with a transition effect or something.

```js
$('.menu__btn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').toggle();
})
```

```css
.menu {
  background: #000;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: none
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
}

.menu__container {
  padding: 85px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu__btn">
  <button class="menu__icon">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__container">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use fadeToggle() instead of only toggle().

Comment: I tried but when i click on the menu button the menu is not appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to animate your menu from left to right.

You can toggle class on the menu and add some transitions and styling. `toggle()` changes from `display:none` to `display:block` , a property which is not animatable.

Use `toggleClass()` to ...well...toggle :)/change classes on the `menu` and style those classes.

So use `left:-100%` and `left:200px` ( if that is where you want to position the menu ) and together with transition or maybe opacity.

See below

```js
$('.menu__btn').click(function(){
  $('.menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
})
```

```css
.menu{
  background: #000;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:-100%;
 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(232,232,232,1);
  transition:1s ease-out;
  opacity:0;
}
.menu__container {
  padding: 85px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  }
  .show-menu {
     left:200px;
     opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu__btn">
 <button class="menu__icon">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="menu">
   <div class="menu__container">
    Some content
   </div>
 </div>
```